# JavaScript: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when posting to discord

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord, webhooks

I have the array **sessionCookies** which looks like this:

```
[ { name: 'cookie_name',
value: 'I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY',
domain: 'cookie domain',
path: '/',
expires: -1,
size: 43,
httpOnly: true,
secure: true,
session: true } ]
```

I am then creating and using the function **findCookie** to get the value "I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY" seen in the array above using this code:

```
    function findCookie(name) {
    for (let i in sessionCookies) {
      if (!sessionCookies.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (sessionCookies[i].name === name) {
        return (sessionCookies[i].value);
      }
    }
  }

  const mycookievalue = findCookie('cookie_name');
```

`console.log(mycookievalue);` then obviously prints out: I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY

I am then trying to send that variable **mycookievalue** to discord using the webhook-discord library however it is throwing me the error: **TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**. This is the code I use to send the webhook:

```
const webhook = require("webhook-discord")
const Hook = new webhook.Webhook("my webhook link")

const msg = new webhook.MessageBuilder()
            .setName("Cookie")
            .setColor("#2fed5c")
            .setText("Got the cookie")
            .addField("My Cookie", mycookievalue)
            .setTime();

Hook.send(msg);
```

That sending to discord is throwing me the error as stated above which I do not know how to get rid of since `JSON.stringify` will not work either. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Get rid of the [ and ] at the beginning and end, I think that might do it.

Comment: @VirxEC unfortunately I can't do that since **sessionCookies** is an array given to me by my puppeteer script's page cookies using `const sessionCookies = await page.cookies();`

Comment: Looks ok, the only place I could see a point of failure is the 'mycookievalue' - can you throw a debugger in there and confirm that it has the value you think it does before sending? Like if you send just regular text opposed to the var mycookievalue, does it send appropriately?  I'm guessing the value it contains isn't quite what it appears to be - for instance, what happens if it doesn't find ''cookie_name'', cause sessionCookies is still async calling and hasn't quite come back yet

Comment: You're working with JavaScript, right? Use this tutorial and you can set your cookies without it -> [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp] Sorry if I misunderstood, but you should be able to use that. and set your object in cookies

Comment: @Kyle **you are right**! Any normal string in "cookie_name" is still giving me the error so it must be a problem with the sending to discord, but I still don't know what...